# Kernel panic - not syncing Attempted to kill init after mount

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, debian-jessie, kernel-panic

I have a VPS running Debian 8 at OVH. Recently I couldn't connect to the SSH because I received the message: "access denied".

So I decided to reset the root password. I followed OVH indications in order to reset the root password:

1. I connected to the web manager and I clicked on the "Reset password" button. After this, the server was restarted in Rescue Mode and I received a new password for the root user on my email.
2. I typed the following commands in order to reset the password:

   fdisk -l

   mount /dev/vdb1 /mnt

   chroot /mnt

   passwd (and I typed the new password two times)

You can find the tutorial here: https://www.ovh.com/us/g2366.change_the_root_password_on_a_vps_linux

3. I rebooted the server from the web manager in order to restart and exit the Rescue mode.

After a few minutes I wasn't able to connect through SSH/FTP/SFTP.

I contacted OVH support and they told me to access the "KVM" button from the web manager, which is an SSH client. I clicked on that button and I saw the following error (I can't scroll in order to see the entre error message):

[image: kernel panic not syncing]

The KVM console was blocked with this error. I couldn't do anything. So I've sent a screenshot with the error to OVH support. Their "experts" recommended me to backup the data and reinstall the VPS from scratch. This is not acceptable. I have an nginx server, PHP, MySql, lots of cron jobs and SSL installed.

Do you have any idea about how can I fix this issue without losing any data? Can I unmount and create a new mount? Should I run an apt-get upgrade/update or some command related to the kernel? Please help, anticipated thanks.

Comment: Can you reboot while the console is open and maybe see the error message before it scrolls off the top?

Comment: I tried. I can't see the error when I reboot. I freezes instantly.

Comment: Most VM consoles close when VM is rebooted. In a normal VM host system there is an option to start the system with console output. I don't know if it is possible at OVH though. You could try starting the VM and immediately try to open the console after starting it to see the other error messages.

Comment: The console is not available during reboot.